# Itextsharp doesnt print Marathi words correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I was working on generating Pdf with printing marathi on it.

Itextsharp version I am using is

[image]

My code

```
 BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\mangal.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
 var font = new Font(baseFont, 10, Font.NORMAL);
 .........
 .........
 var cell= new PdfPCell(new Phrase(prod.ProductName, font));
 .........
 table.AddCell(cell);
```

Now there is one word in my database i.e सिमला मिर्च, अर्बी के पत्ते. but these words are not printed correctly. But when I copy these words and paste it anywhere, those word are in required format. Please check image below

[image: Word not printed correctly]

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 3):

See [this post on the iText message board](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Ligature-pdf-examples-tp4658416p4658429.html).  Basically, non-Arabic ligatures are not supported and won't be supported.

Comment: thanks, so there is no meaning in googling solution for this issue?

Comment: Yes, looks like you are out of luck.  Sorry.